# How to read testdata/Json in cypress only once system wide?

Tags: cypress, fixtures

This can be very easy but I cannot find a solution, I have seen pretty much everywhere that to read json from fixture directory one need to use `describe` which contains test(`it`) which can use the `fixture` data.

Can't there be a way where you just import testdata once, put it in a variable and use that variable pretty much anywhere you want in any of the tests, rather putting the test inside `describe` which gets the data in fixture.
I mean its weird you have the read the same json so many times. Especially if its system wide.
Or
What would be the solution when you are using `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`; you do not have a `it` block then.
If conventional way doesn't exist, please provide a clean hack.

Sorry for the long text.

Comment: You can use the `cypress.json` file as an alternative to reading your data globally in your tests. Will that fulfill your use case? Or you're only looking for a solution that involves using fixture files only?

Comment: @AlapanDas I have multiple files which I want to load  in my test, different files diff test, some files in multiple tests, I can place those anywhere I want, preferably fixture folder.
Cannot put everything in cypress.json.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by importing all your fixtures file in the `before()` or `beforeEach()` inside `support/index.js` file. [(Cypress Doc Reference)](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Support-file)

So your code should look like:

1.Inside `support/index.js`:

```
before(function() {
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.fixture('testdata').then(function(testdata) {
    this.testdata = testdata
  })
})
```

2.Inside your tests directly use the data from your fixtures -

```
describe('All tests', function() {
  it('test1', function() {
    cy.get('#txtUsername').type(this.testdata.username)
    cy.get('#txtPassword').type(this.testdata.password)
  })
})
```

This works because - By default Cypress will automatically include the support file `cypress/support/index.js`. This file runs before every single spec file. The order of the execution looks something like:

[image: Execution sequence]

But there is a catch. This will work with Single/All File execution with `cypress run` and only Single File execution with `cypress open`.

In the case of 'Running All Specs' in `cypress open` the Test Runner bundles and concatenates all specs together, in essence running scripts like shown below. This means the code in the support file is executed once before all spec files, instead of once before each spec file.

[image: Execution order in case of Running all specs]

Comment: What is the catch? Does Cypress clear down the loaded fixtures after spec-a?

Comment: And does the same happen with `cypress run`?

Comment: This will not work only in the case when you are running all specs with the Test runner `cypress open`, as all the spec files are bundled as one, and `support/index.js` is executed just once. For `cypress run` in case of execution of all spec files, a new browser window is opened for each support and spec file pair.

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer that you can use both `before()` and `beforeEach()` inside `support/index.js`

Comment: So why does it not work when running all specs in `cypress open`?

Comment: I think the catch is you can no longer use `cy.visit()` in individual specs. Or use arrow functions.

Comment: I believe you can use `cy.visit()` in individual spec files if you want to, just not write it in the support/index.js file